# Hide dialog box after touching it

Tags: android

In my app i am creating a messageBox and i want to make it invisible if i touch inside it
the code i am using to create the message is

```
public void messageBox2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Dialog    myDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.PauseDialog);
       myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.customhelp);
       myDialog.setTitle("Help");
       myDialog.setCancelable(true);
              myDialog.show();
}
```

I want to make it disappear if i click anywhere in the message box

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by setting `setOnClickListener` to parent layout of Dialog as :

```
RelativeLayout relativelayout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
relativelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
             public void onClick(View v){
                 // cancel dialog here
               myDialog.dismiss();
             }
         });
```

Comment: It will make it disappear if i touch outside the Box..I want to make it disappear if i touch inside it

Comment: @ammukuttylive : ok , which layout you are using in for Dialog window ?

Comment: Relative Layout i am using

Comment: @ammukuttylive : maybe you will need set `android:clickable="true"` for RelativeLayout in xml

Comment: I had done that in xml, what i am supposed to do in java class

Comment: @ammukuttylive : in java code you can do same as  `relativelayout.setClickable(true);`

Answer (score 0):

in your layout create a button in `customhelp` code will follows

```
close_btn   =   (Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
close_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```